# Clickable Image

Tags: java, android, image, imagemap

I am attempting to code into my android app an image that is rescaleable with the following code

```
    package million.tyler;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Matrix;
    import android.graphics.PointF;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.util.FloatMath;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Touch implements OnTouchListener {

     // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
     Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

     // We can be in one of these 3 states
     static final int NONE = 0;
     static final int DRAG = 1;
     static final int ZOOM = 2;
     int mode = NONE;

     // Remember some things for zooming
     PointF start = new PointF();
     PointF mid = new PointF();
     float oldDist = 1f;


     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
      // Dump touch event to log
      dumpEvent(event);

      // Handle touch events here...
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       savedMatrix.set(matrix);
       start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
       mode = DRAG;
       break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
       oldDist = spacing(event);
       if (oldDist > 10f) {
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        midPoint(mid, event);
        mode = ZOOM;
       }
       break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
       mode = NONE;
       break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
       if (mode == DRAG) {
                // ...    
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);    
       } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
        float newDist = spacing(event);
        if (newDist > 10f) {
         matrix.set(savedMatrix);
         float scale = newDist / oldDist;
         matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
        }
       }
       break;
      }

      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      return true; // indicate event was handled
     }

     /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
     private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
        "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              int action = event.getAction();
      int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
      sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
      if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
        || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
       sb.append("(pid ").append(
         action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
       sb.append(")");
      }
      sb.append("[");
      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
       sb.append("#").append(i);
       sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
       sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
       sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
       if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
        sb.append(";");
      }
      sb.append("]");
     }

     /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
     private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
      return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
     }

     /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
     private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
      point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
     }
```

Along with this, I would like the image to be clickable in different regions. Sort of like an image map in html. I am new to coding so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can achieved by Specifying the specific coordinates for the image like if user tapped in (0,0 to 100,100) fire some event.

Or there is another way of doing things. You can use webview instead of imageview for loading of images. You can simply make HTML Map's for images and then can perform different functions. Further you can get javascript events in your android code...
Explore more by yourself...:P